# Find currently visible div in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, effects

I have a four divs all set `display:none` and on document.ready i am showing the first div.. I have 4 link buttons link1,link2...link4... I showing div1 on link1 click and so on.. How to find which div is currently visible in jquery?

```
 <style type="text/css">
        .ContentDivs
        {
            width: 90%;
            height: 300px;
            border: solid 5px #404040;
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div>
            <a id="Link1" href="#">Link1</a> 
            <a id="Link2" href="#">Link2</a>
             <a id="Link3" href="#">Link3</a> 
             <a id="Link4" href="#">Link4</a>
        </div>
        <div id="div1" class="ContentDivs">
        DIv1
        </div>
        <div id="div2" class="ContentDivs">
        Div2
        </div>
        <div id="div3" class="ContentDivs">
        Div3
        </div>
        <div id="div4" class="ContentDivs">
        Div4
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
              $("#div1").show().fadeIn("slow");
        });
        $('#Link1').click(function() {
        $(".ContentDivs").fadeOut("fast");//find current div here?
            $("#div1").show().fadeIn("slow");
        });
        $('#Link2').click(function() {
        $(".ContentDivs").fadeOut("fast");//find current div here?
            $("#div2").show().fadeIn("slow");
        });
        $('#Link3').click(function() {
        $(".ContentDivs").fadeOut("fast");//find current div here?
            $("#div3").show().fadeIn("slow");
        });
        $('#Link4').click(function() {
        $(".ContentDivs").fadeOut("fast");//find current div here?
            $("#div4").show().fadeIn("slow");
        });
    </script>
```

See the effect here http://jsbin.com/umode4/edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

with lesserr codes, you could do it this way...

## jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#div1").show().fadeIn("slow");
    });
    $('.links a').click(function() {
        $(".ContentDivs:visible").fadeOut("fast");//find current div here?
        $("#div" + ($(this).index()+1)).show().fadeIn("slow");
    });
</script>
```

## html

```
<div>
    <div class="links">
        <a id="Link1" href="#">Link1</a> 
        <a id="Link2" href="#">Link2</a>
        <a id="Link3" href="#">Link3</a> 
        <a id="Link4" href="#">Link4</a>
    </div>
    <div id="div1" class="ContentDivs">
        DIv1
    </div>
    <div id="div2" class="ContentDivs">
        Div2
    </div>
    <div id="div3" class="ContentDivs">
        Div3
    </div>
    <div id="div4" class="ContentDivs">
        Div4
    </div>
</div>
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3zDyR/)

Comment: In your demo when i click a new link2 the divs overlap... I just want to hide the visible div and fadein the next div..

Comment: Exactly like SO ask question page title textbox click and textarea click right hand side div fade effect...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) filter selector for that.

```
$('.ContentDivs:visible').........
```

**Update:**

An easier approach will be to give each of your links a `rel` attribute with the same value as the id of divs and a class, eg:

```
<a rel="Link1" class="link" href="#">Link1</a> 
<a rel="Link2" class="link" href="#">Link1</a>
```

And divs:

```
<div id="Link1">
  Div1
</div>

<div id="Link2">
  Div2
</div>
```

And then all you need is to get the rel of clicked link and show/hide the corresponding div:

```
$('a.link').click(function(){
  var rel = $(this).attr('rel');

  if ($('div#' + rel).is(':visible'))
  {
    $('div#' + rel).fadeOut('fast');
  }
  else
  {
    $('div#' + rel).fadeIn('fast');
  }

  return false;
});
```

Comment: @sarfraz look at my link i want to display the div corresponding to th e link with a fadein effect...

Comment: @sarfraz even now you didnt get my point... Exactly like SO ask question page `title` textbox click and `textarea` click right hand side div fade effect...

Answer (score 2):

**Use**

```
$(".ContentDivs:visible");
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var displayedDiv = $('div.ContentDivs').filter(':visible');
```

or even this

```
   var displayedDiv = $('div.ContentDivs').filter(function(){
       if($(this).css('display') != 'none')
          return true;
       else
          return false;
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

HTML

```
<div>
    <div id="links">
        <a id="Link1" href="#" rel="div1">Link1</a> 
        <a id="Link2" href="#" rel="div2">Link2</a>
         <a id="Link3" href="#" rel="div3">Link3</a> 
         <a id="Link4" href="#" rel="div4">Link4</a>
    </div>

    <div id="div1" class="ContentDivs">
    DIv1
    </div>
    <div id="div2" class="ContentDivs">
    Div2
    </div>
    <div id="div3" class="ContentDivs">
    Div3
    </div>
    <div id="div4" class="ContentDivs">
    Div4
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {
    $("#links a").click( function () {
        $(".ContentDivs").css( "display", "none");
        $("#"+this.rel+".ContentDivs").fadeIn();
    });

});
```